# Why can I not replace BigInteger("1") with BigInteger.ONE?

Tags: java

I am writing a Fibonacci program.

```
public class ImperativeFibonacci implements Fibonacci {
  public BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
    BigInteger nextFibonacci = new BigInteger("1"), currentFibonacci = new BigInteger("1"); 

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      nextFibonacci = currentFibonacci.add(nextFibonacci);
      currentFibonacci = nextFibonacci.subtract(currentFibonacci);
    }

    return nextFibonacci;
  }
}
```

I want to replace line 3 with:

```
BigInteger nextFibonacci = new BigInteger.ONE, currentFibonacci = new BigInteger.ONE;
```

But it doesn’t work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`BigInteger.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE) is a **constant** and already has an instance. Remove `new`. Like

```
BigInteger nextFibonacci = BigInteger.ONE, currentFibonacci = BigInteger.ONE;
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `ONE` is a `final static` field of `BigNumber` class, it doesn't make any sense to pair it with `new` keyword, you don't want to allocate a `BigNumber.ONE`, you want to use it straight away, just remove the keyword:

```
BigInteger nextFibonacci = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger currentFibonacci = new BigInteger.ONE;
```

What you are trying to do is trying to use `new` with a variable declaration, eg:

```
BigNumber NUMBER = new BigNumber("1");
BigNumber other = new NUMBER;
              //  ^^^ doesn't make any sense
```

Answer (score -2):

```
BigInteger nextFibonacci = new BigInteger.ONE
```

change it to:

```
BigInteger nextFibonacci = BigInteger.ONE
```

Comment: Please *explain* your answer